# The algorithm inverse number

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, visual-c++, inversion

Is this a formula for the inverse number?

eg 123-321?

Number is K

inv K= K%100 + K/10%10 * 10 + K % 10 *100

I'm not sure I exactly wrote, and I need this right for the task at school for graphic algorithm

Edit:Yes i'm stupid xD I'm Beginner xD

Comment: I would separate the calculations more to make them easier to follow, like `units = K %10; tens = ...; hundreds = ...;` and then when the digits are all separate,  combine them again `inv = 100 * units + 10 * tens + hundreds;`.

Comment: You're not very clear as to what you're asking. Is `123-321` a string you receive and have to verify it's a palindrome? of you you receive `123` and have to return `321`? Will the numbers you receive always 3 digits long?

Comment: I do not need this to write a program, but I would draw an algorithm for the number of 3 digits.
It is good way or not?

my english is suck sorry xD

Comment: From a logic standpoint, what you wrote **looks** correct, but is a very specific solution to the problem. If you code it, you may have to be careful with operation precedence, though, so may need to add brackets for clarification.

Comment: Convert the number to a string (library function). Reverse the string. Convert that string to another number (library function) - but watch out for [octal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) if a leading `0` is present! Then subtract the two numbers.

Comment: `K%100` typo as `K/100`

Comment: If you need to reverse a number, keep it as a string, then use methods to revers the string.

Comment: Yes, if you only need to print the reversed number and not to use it as a number, then it has sense to read and reverse directly as string. But do not **convert** it to string and back, because that is very wasteful compared to doing it directly in int (dynamic memory allocation for string etc.).

Answer (score 3):

This logic will help you. variable inverse is the output.

```
        int num = 123;
        double inverse = 0;
        while (num != 0)
        {
            inverse = inverse * 10;
            inverse = inverse + num % 10;
            num = num / 10;                
        }
```

Comment: Why type of `inverse` is `double` instead of `int` ?

Comment: Thanks Mr. J. Piquard for your comment... It should be int. But there is no issue with double also.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your code to work with any number, consider converting to a string and then reversing it!

```
int invert( int input )
{
    std::stringstream str;
    str << input;

    std::string s = str.str();
    std::reverse(s.begin(),s.end());

    return atoi( s.c_str() );
}
```

Comment: I'd prefer to do it directly in integer instead of doing unnecessary conversions to/from string (involving dynamic memory allocations btw.).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int i = 123045 , j = 0,k=0;

    while( i != 0 )
        {
        j=i%10;
        k = k *10 + j;
        i /=10;
    }

    printf("%d\n", k);
    return 0;
}
```

Output
`540321`

Comment: In each iteration of the while loop `i%10` will extract the first digit from right. This digit is carried over to `k` by `j` and we remove the digit from `i` by using integer division.

Comment: This will not work for number containing zero, e.g. 12305, the termination condition is wrong.

Comment: Modified; Thanks for bringing this up!